# Connot get a working InterMine data-warehouse

Tags: linux, postgresql, github, ubuntu-14.04, intermine

I have a problem while trying to run the second and third script:

```
`# Set up tomcat` 
 ./config/download_and_configure_tomcat.sh
 # For a genomic application, with test data from Malaria
 ./biotestmine/setup.sh
 # For the testmodel
 ./testmodel/setup.sh
```

The second script displays an error : **Could not access database: db.production**
The third displays: **Could not access database: db.unittest**

[image: Result after running the second scipt]

Comment: I know it's been a while since you posted this, but did you ever manage to resolve it? Do you still need to? (Asking as an InterMiner here)